# Survival Probabilities

Tags: probability-theory

Consider an article whose lifetime $X$ takes integral values $0,1,2,...$ and define $p_j=P(X=j)$. If we define also 
$$ 
b_j=P(X=j+1|X>j)=\frac{p_{j+1}}{\sum\limits_{k=j+1}^{\infty} p_{k}}   
$$

We can interprept this as the failure probability. Correspondingly, $a_j=1-b_j$ is the survival probability. Show that $P(X>j)=a_0*a_1*...a_{j-1}*a_j$.

Attempt at Solution: First I noted that $$a_j=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=j+2}^{\infty} p_{k}}{\sum\limits_{k=j+1}^{\infty} p_{k}}=P(X>j+1|X>j)$$ 
Then I let $A_n$ be the event the article lives past n years and noted that $A_j=A_0\cap A_1\cap...\cap  A_j$ 
$$ 
P(A_0\cap A_1\cap...\cap  A_j)= P(A_0)*P(A_1|A_0)*P(A_2|A_1)*...*P(A_j|A_{j-1})$$

This is equal to $P(X>0)*a_0*a_1*...*a_{j-1}$ so it is not quite right infact I think it may be wrong because it would imply that $P(X>0)=a_{j}$ which is not true I think. So if you could point out my mistake and point me in the direction of a correct solution I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$a_j=\frac{P(X\gt j+1)}{P(X\gt j)}$$ hence $$a_{j-1}a_{j-2}\cdots a_{0}=\frac{P(X\gt j)P(X\gt j-1)\cdots P(X\gt1)}{P(X\gt j-1)P(X\gt j-2)\cdots P(X\gt0)}=\frac{P(X\gt j)}{P(X\gt0)},$$ and $$a_{j-1}a_{j-2}\cdots a_{0}a_{-1}=P(X\gt j).$$

Comment: $X$ can be zero though so I do not think last equality is right but you confirmed what I found that $a_0*a_1*...*a_{j-1}*P(X>0)=P(X>j)$.

Comment: Need to find a way to move that up by one index to $a_j*a_{j-1}*...*a_0$. Unless book misprinted that is supposed to be answer.